# wordpress access management articles

Tags: wordpress, plug

I have a question please, I would like to know if there is a plguin that allows you to manage access to articles according to the role.

For example I have two categories (Questionnaire, surveys) and each category contains articles
I want a user group to have the right to access certain articles of the survey category, but not to have the right to access other articles of the same category (survey)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the keywords **restrict page access wordpress** or **restrict user access wordpress** on the choice of your search engine.

or you can try content control plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/